# Phrase for "Night Haystacker"

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, translation, proverbs

I want a proverb, a metaphor, or a figure of speech about someone who collects non-selectively and carries a heavy load that hurts him. He wants to quickly unload it. In Arabic, we say a *night haystacker*. He works at night so all he can do is collect hay without being able to select the good stuff. Also, that the load hurts him, he wants to quickly unload.

This is a title of an article about beginning translators who choose any offer and are in a hurry to deliver to the customer and relieve themselves from the pressure.

Comment: I will note that the songs "Banana Boat Song" and "Sixteen Tons" capture some sense of this (though not exactly the same).  (But "another day older and deeper in debt", and "I owe my soul to the company sto" are pretty good idioms.)

Comment: Welcome, Nour Negm. I suggest there is no language in which "a night haystacker" by itself could convey any such thing. If you doubt that, why can you not prove the case by direct translation?

Clearly, "a night haystacker" might be a standard idiomatic reference to a complete story but was it my job to extract that fact, or yourn to have Posted it in the first place?

Not fair, Nour Negm.

Comment: In my opinion, this is a cool expression. I don’t see any reason why you can’t title the article “The Night Haystacker” and introduce the meaning of the title within the first few paragraphs. You’d only need a few sentences recapping the proverb.

Comment: And I will note that "working yourself to death" is a fairly common idiom.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Why do you think it might be a reference to a story? In English, we have figurative "black sheep" which reference no sort of story that I know of, but it remains idiomatic across English phrase-and-proverb land, which is admittedly narrower than Arabic phrase-and-proverb land. In Spanish, too, we make a point to have a proverb to answer almost every situation!

Comment: Conrado, I hope it's a reference to a story because there cannot be enough information in the term "night haystacker" to convey anything like the meaning "one who collects non-selectively and carries a heavy load that hurts him. He wants to quickly unload it… " Not in Arabic, not in English, not in Spanish nor in any other language, ever.

"Black sheep" needs no reference to any actual story. That the market wants white wool should speak for itself in Arabic, English, Spanish or in any other language.

Could you look at the details?

Answer (score 2):

"**The lazy donkey kills himself with one load**."

In stead, he should go back and forth, carrying smaller loads, but still effectively get the task done--only, he does not want to take so much time, so he carries it all, and risks breaking his back.

A quick Google search doesn't show up any relevant results, when I find something I'll update. However, my aunt Eileen, who was English, and my grandmother, who is American, both used it.

Comment: I couldn't find it either. +1, it's a great one!! (I'm wondering about its origin :D)

Answer (score 2):

**"... bit off more than he could chew"**

This has some of the implication you're asking for, in that someone attempted to do too big of a job too quickly and found themselves unable to complete it.  It doesn't have the "heavy load" part of the original phrase, but it's metaphorical.  It can also apply to a situation where you rashly jump into a scenario you're unprepared for, e.g. the soldier that charges into a firefight against what first seems like a small group of enemies and then realizes he's stumbled across a much larger force than he was expecting and is hopelessly outgunned.

Answer (score 1):

**Glutton for punishment** seems to fit some aspects of what you're looking for. Someone who is a "glutton for punishment" eagerly takes on tasks that others (or even himself) might find unpleasant. It might be because the person is incapable of saying no, or because they are "paying their dues" by doing otherwise undesirable tasks, or it could even be the case that the person actually enjoys these tasks (although in that case, only other people, and not the person themself, would use the term).

It might fit your desired usage of a translator who consistently chooses bad clients with short deadlines - they might have the power to choose their jobs more carefully, but since they are a "glutton for punishment", they keep coming back to the same patterns that result in a poor working relationship. The phrase mainly connotes the habitual nature of self-inflicted, unpleasant situations, but it doesn't address the desire to quickly exit the situation.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is good enough for you but you might want to try working with the idiom *have too much on one's plate*.

**Have too much on one's plate:** take too much responsibility/work etc. that is difficult to "digest" — [**TFD**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+too+much+on+plate)

I think you can make a few tweaks to the idiom's structure, eg. *have/get/take...*; maybe *on sb's plate* as well (?).

Comment: I think this implies that someone has too much work to do but through no fault of their own necessarily.  It gets the overworked part of the original phrase, but not the rashness that put them into the situation.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman In its basic form - it does. However, you can use "take" instead of "have", and voila! :)

Answer (score 0):

An excellent phrase!  I don't know of any direct match though.

For this specific instance, you could describe the translator's work as resulting in **quantity over quality** (combined with @JulesCocovin's suggestion) due to having too much on their plate.

To contrast, some almost-matches:

- a **hoarder** or **indiscriminate collector** acquires plenty of things, but does not want to get rid of them.
- a **jack-of-all-trades** is *able* to take on all manner of work, but does fairly well at it, rather than poorly.

Comment: AFAIK what the context of the article is, "hoarder" might be a nice option to work with (in a figurative sense, not clinical).